# Unity Engine - UGUI layout on mobile is different from how it is in the editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development

I've been struggling with thos for a bit now, but I can't seem to figure out why it is.

When I design my UI in the Unity Engine Editor, it fits nicely inside the canvas. However, when I run my game on my phone, it has a offset to the left, which looks very ugly. I don't understand why that is.

Following this is some information, so that you know what I mean and hopefully can help me figure out why this is and how to fix it.

These are the settings of my Canvas (I use my phone's screen size as reference):

[image: Canvas Settings]

This is how it looks in the unitys game preview:

[image: Unity Game Preview]

And finally, this is how it looks on my mobile:

[image: Game on Mobile]

EDIT: I have boiled the problem a little bit down. When I set the position in the editor, it's equal to -1440. When I start the game on phone, for some reason, its -1416. Can someone explain why this translation happens?

Answer (score 0):

In the "Game" tab on the top-left corner you should set same resolution as your phone have (now you have selected "motorola g7 power..." preset).
Also, are you sure about 1570 x 720? Clearly you have different aspect ratio in canvas settings and in game window.

Comment: The "preset" is a custom I made, it's resolution is equal. And there's clearly the same aspect ratio...
"The Motorola Moto G7 Power screen has a 6.2-inch size with resolution 1570 × 720 px [...]"